# (XAMPP) phpMyAdmin error phpmyadmin.pma__tracking

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have installed XAMPP on Mac OS X. After starting the Apache Server and the MySQL server, I can launch the phpMyAdmin web interface. But each time I try to see the content of a database, I got an error like:

```
SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'phpmyadmin'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABASE',tracking) > 0

#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

After some digging on the Internet, I've tried to recreate the `phpmyadmin` database with the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/sql/create_tables.sql` file (through the "Import" tab in phpMyAdmin). And I got the same error:

```
SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 'phpmyadmin'  AND `table_name` = ''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABASE',tracking) > 0

#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

I can use, create and manage database by running `mysql` command in a terminal, but I need to fix the graphical interface for maintenance purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved (more or less, but it works...)

Everything looks fine using XAMPP 5.6.12 instead of 5.6.14